# Why go http post gets different result than curl post?

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a Rest API login process. I have verified the process with `curl`.

With `curl`, the following command will do the login:

```
$ curl -i -X POST  https://the-service.mycompany.com/login -d username=<my username> -d password=<mypassword>
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 302
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, content-type, authorization, X-RateLimit-App, X-Spinnaker-Priority
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-AUTH-REDIRECT-URL
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: SESSION=ODdmNGZjZmEtY2EwOC00YzA4LWFmMmYtMjAwNDI1ODM2NjI3; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Location: http://the-service.mycompany.com
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2019 14:38:40 GMT
```

This command will successfully and returns a cookie in response.

But when I tried to use Go code:

```
http := http.Client{
}

const body = "username=myuser&password=mypass"
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://the-service.mycompany.com/login", strings.NewReader(body))
req.Header.Add("Accept", "*/*")
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.Header.Del("Accept-Encoding")
dump, err := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, true)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%q\n", dump)

resp, err := client.Do(req)

dump, err = httputil.DumpRequestOut(resp.Request, true)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%q\n", dump)

fmt.Println("Dump response ==================")
fmt.Println(resp.Status)
for k, v := range resp.Header {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k, v)
}
```

It returned a different response than `curl` gets, meaning that both response header and body are totally different.

I noticed that, `curl` returns two status code, 200 and 302. But the `go` code's `resp.Status` is 200.

The `go` code output is:

```
"POST /login HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: the-service.mycompany.com\r\nUser-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1\r\nContent-Length: 36\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\nusername=myuser&password=mypass"
"GET /login HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: the-service.mycompany.com\r\nUser- Agent: Go-http-client/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nReferer: http://the-service.mycompany.com/login\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n"
Dump response ==================
200 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [*]
Access-Control-Max-Age: [3600]
Cache-Control: [no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate]
Date: [Thu, 18 Jul 2019 14:53:07 GMT]
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: [true]
Content-Type: [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
X-Xss-Protection: [1; mode=block]
Pragma: [no-cache]
X-Frame-Options: [DENY]
X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: [x-requested-with, content-type, authorization, X-RateLimit-App, X-Spinnaker-Priority]
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: [X-AUTH-REDIRECT-URL]
Expires: [0]
Content-Length: [1324]
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: [POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH]
```

From the output, before do post, the request is a POST, but in when I dump `resp.Request`, it becomes to a `GET`, why?

Comment: What did `http.Post` return?

Comment: "returned a different response" meaning what? What responses do you get from each?

Comment: @Adria meaning that response header and body are totally different.

Comment: @JimWright http.Post returns same thing as http.PostForm.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example? The code here isn't valid.

Comment: @JimB I have fixed the bug in code.

Comment: Look at the complete requests sent; these should be creating very similar requests.

Comment: @JimB How to see request generated by `go` code?

Comment: @TieDad: same way as any client, check it on the wire, or send the request to something that will print it out. Both of these should create nearly identical requests, it's not unheard of for server to return different results based on User-Agent.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut

Comment: @JimB I updated the question a little bit. Looks like `curl` returns 2 status code, 200 and 302, but go post only returns 200.

Comment: @TieDad Go's probably getting the `302` too, and following it.

Comment: Yep, they're doing the same thing, they just tell you about it in different ways. They both issue the POST, get a 302 response redirect, follow the redirect by placing a new GET request, and get a 200 back from that.

Comment: Finally, after 6 hours sleep, I got the problem. Where `curl` didn't follow redirect (because I didn't use `-L` option), but `go` code followed redirect. I added `CheckRedirect` to block redirecting, then I got same result as `curl`. Thanks for all of your good suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I figured out the problem. Let me do a self answer, hopefully it helps future people if they hit similar issue.

Actually, in my case, `curl` didn't auto redirect, because I didn't use `-L` option with `curl`. But the go POST did auto redirect.

So I added a `CheckRedirect` function to block redirecting:

```
func check(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
    return http.ErrUseLastResponse
}

... in main() ...

    client := http.Client {
        CheckRedirect: check,
    }
```

Then `client.PostForm` returns same 302 result as what `curl` gets.